# How to achieve effect of shrinking picture?

Tags: animation, javafx

I'd like to hide a picture which is on JavaFX application's stage. I want it disappear by shrinking.

Let's says there are some:

```
@FXML
private ImageView iv;
private Image img = new Image(...);
```

real `img` size is 100x100 pixels

then

```
iv.setImage(img);
iv.setFitWidth(50);
```

next I made method like that:

```
private Timeline shrink(ImageView iv)
   {
        final Timeline animation = new Timeline();

           animation.getKeyFrames().addAll(
                   new KeyFrame(Duration.ZERO,
                           new KeyValue(iv.fitWidthProperty(), 50)
                   ),
                   new KeyFrame(Duration.millis(400),
                           new KeyValue(iv.fitWidthProperty(), 0)
                   )
           );
        animation.setCycleCount(1);
        animation.play();
    }
```

so after that, the picture is shrinking, but it doesn't stay with 0 width, even worse, it appears again in its original size: 100.

what should I do to stay it shrinked ? I don't want to hide it by `setVisibile` cause I need that extra space later to fill it with some text.

Comment: Depends on the desired effects on the parent layout and the desired pivot point of the transformation...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ok, my fault...

`0` is for default, so that is why picture appears in its original size. It needs to be set to `0.01` for example and then maybe set the visibility to false. But i'm sure there is better and nicer way to do it.